# Do I need a Microsoft Developer Edition Tools license to code in VBA in Office 2000 thru Office 2007?

Tags: vba

I have a job involving old versions of VBA/Access code I'm tasked with fixing. To my utter dismay, the only version of Microsoft Office Developer Edition Tools I can find to fix this company's problems with their pre Office 2010 Access VBA coded screens is an Office 97 version, which is a vald license of the Microsoft Office 97 Developer Edition Tools.  My question is this: supposing I get there and the guy has it coded in Office 2003.  Am I going to have to go out on the web and try to find an old Developer Tools for 2003 just to do the work?  Same thing if its 2007 I find in use.  Basically, I need to know whether I can even do dev work on Office 2003 or 2007 or even 2010 without a developers licence, like we had to in the old days, or whether I will be able to edit & fix code issues in the older versions if the company I go to does not have the developers licence versions appropriate for the work in these older versions of Office.  I know for a fact that, until the versions like Office 2013, 2016, and 365, you needed a dev licence that cost extra money but you can develop right out of the box on the newer ones.  But that begs the question of what I will need to do the work in on of the version from the wayback machine, such as 2000, 2003, or 2007.  Thats what I need an answer to.

Comment: VBA doesn't need any kind of developer licence - just an office licence

Comment: Thanks. Like you, I get it that current versions come with VBA but in days gone by, the appropriate Developer's Tools license for each Office version was needed.  To do VBA work in 2003, for example, I needed the 2003 Dev license.  I expect to need to tell them they must upgrade to Office Business 2019 or 365 & perhaps Win 10 also. I doubt I'll find they own the appropriate Dev license.  What I tell them needs to be 100% accurate. See my reason for asking?  So, does anyone know which Office version was the first to begin including VBA without the need for a Dev licence? 2007? 2010? 2013?

Comment: I've never heard of VBA needing any kind of licence beyond the Office licence. Happy to be proven wrong. Or do you just mean "Microsoft Office Developer Edition Tools"? I've never needed to use that.